# Organizing a Barcode String output

Tags: ios, string, barcode, barcode-scanner

I'm Building an IOS App that scans 2D barcodes. Everything is going well with the scanning part, but when I get the text output from the scanner Its obviously not organized. I'd like to know if there is an easy way of organizing that output. Keeping in mind the field separator is always different, and pattern is not always the same.

Bellow are few examples of the output I`m getting.

\"210774$$ROBERT$DAVIDSON$PRESIDENT$PATENT.COM INC$255 INDUSTRIAL PKWY S UNIT 1$$AURORA$ON$L4G 3V5$CANADA$9057556514$$CSR@PATENT.COM$EX$$$\""

\" 69303743  DAVE  ANDERSON   TRIPORT INC.  8644 WOODBINE AVE.  MARKHAM ON L3R 8B9 CANADA (905)4771755  (905)4757755        960921            \""

\"07-2933;JOHN;RABEA;;;JET SERVICES;550 KEATS ROAD;;MONTREAL;QC;CANADA;H9H 3M6;5144482886;;ATAABL2A2B2C2D2G2I2J2K2L3E4A5A7C;info@jetservices.ca;\""

PS The info above are for dummy contacts
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Zbar to scan barcodes, because it is giving perfect output, easy to integrate and good documentation is there. See their site http://zbar.sourceforge.net/.
And see their tutorial http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/tutorial.html. I had successfully integrated Zbar in many of my projects.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Mine is successfully working to. Zbar will generate the same output. I`m looking for the best way to arrange this output.